# Differentiable homeomorphism between continuous random variables

Tags: random-variables

First, let me apologize if the question is not formulated appropriately. I'm a bit rusty in math lately.

Let $X$ be a continuous random variable in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and $N\sim\mathcal{N}(0, \mathbb{1}_d)$ be the standard multidimensional normal distribution. Then, I want to know if:

$\exists H: R^d \rightarrow R^d$ such that:

- $X = H(N)$
- $H$ is an homeomorphism.
- $H$ and $H^{-1}$ are differentiable.

In other words, I want to know if the existence of a continuous, invertible and differentiable mapping between any continuous random variable and the standard normal is guaranteed. I don't need an explicit formal proof, just some pointers of why this is true (if it is) or a counterexample if not.

Answer (score 0):

Take  $d=1, X=N^{2}$. If $X=H(N)$ then $x^{2}=H(x)$ almost everywhere w.r.t. Lebesgue measure. By continuity this implies $H(x)=x^{2}$ for all $x$ so $H$ is not one-to-one.

More generally, if $K$ is any continuous function then $K(N)=H(N)$ implies $K \equiv N$. So if you start with a function $K$ which does  not satisfy your requirements you get a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, it was quite obvious in the end, I didn’t think of that.